# ATP/WTA ranking during Grand Slam tournaments

Tags: tennis, ranking, atp, wta

As far as I know, the ATP and WTA rankings work approximately this way: Each week the points for the tournaments played that week are added. The points for tournaments more than 52 weeks old are dropped. (Of course, there are more complicated rules about which and how many tournaments are counted, but this should be the gist of it.)

My question is what happens during Grand Slams, which last two weeks. Some players do not play at GS tournaments, so they might play some tournament during the first week. However, if the new ranking would be issued after one week of GS tournaments, what should be done? Dropping the points for the last edition of the same GS tournament seems unfair, since the players did not finish the tournament yet?

> - Is the new edition of WTA/ATP rankings issued after the first week of the GS tournament? Are the points for Grand Slams dropped/counted only after the two-week period, in which the tournament is played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Grand Slam events - new rankings aren't calculated after the first week. New rankings are calculated after the Grand Slam event is over, so after the end of those 2 weeks.

As far as rankings points go - the points expire (like you said, after 52 weeks) whether they play the same event the following year or not.